# Python: Compute all possible pairwise distances of a list (DTW)

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I have a list of items like so: `T=[T_0, T_1, ..., T_N]` where each of `T_i` is itself a time series. I want to find the pairwise distances (via DTW) for all potential pairs.

E.g. If `T=[T_0, T_1, T_2]` and I had a DTW function `f`, I want to find `f(T_0, T_1), f(T_0, T_2), f(T_1, T_2)`.

Note `T_i` actually looks like `( id of i, [ time series values ] )`.

My code snippet looks like this:

```
cluster = defaultdict( list )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
donotcluster = defaultdict( list )                                                                                                                          
for i, lst1 in tqdm(enumerate(T)):                                                                                                           
    for lst2 in tqdm(T):                                                                                                                     
        if lst2 in cluster[lst1[0]] or lst2 in donotcluster[lst1[0]]:                                                                                       
            pass                                                                                                                                            
        else:                                                                                                                                               
            distance, path = fastdtw(lst1[1], lst2[1], dist=euclidean)                                                                                      
            if distance <= distance_threshold:                                                                                                              
                cluster[lst1[0]] += [ lst2 ]                                                                                                                
                cluster[lst2[0]] += [ lst1 ]                                                                                                                
            else:                                                                                                                                           
                donotcluster[lst1[0]] += [ lst2 ]                                                                                                           
                donotcluster[lst2[0]] += [ lst1 ]
```

Right now I have around 20,000 time series and this take way too long (it will run in about 5 days). I am using the python library `fastdtw`. Is there a more optimised library? Or just a better/faster way of computing all possible distances? Since distances are symmetric I don't have to calculate for example `f(T_41,T_33)` if I have already calculated `f(T_33, T_41)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **keeping a `set` of all of the pairs you've done so far**, keeping in mind that `set` has a constant time lookup operation. Besides that, you should consider other approaches where you **don't extend your lists so often** (that nasty `+=` you're doing) since it can be rather expensive. I don't know enough of the implementation of your application to comment on that though. If you provide more information, I may be able to figure a way to get rid of some of the `+=` that you don't need. One idea (for efficiency) would be to `append` each list to a list of lists, and then flatten it at the end of your script with something like

```
[i for x in cluster[lst[0]] for i in x]
```

I modified your code as follows:

```
cluster = defaultdict( list )
donotcluster = defaultdict( list )
seen = set() # added this
for i, lst1 in tqdm(enumerate(T)):
    for lst2 in tqdm(T):
        if hashPair( lst1[1], lst2[1] ) not in seen and lst2 not in cluster[lst1[0]] and lst2 not in donotcluster[lst1[0]]: # changed around your condition
            seen.add( hashPair( lst1[1], lst2[1] ) # added this
            distance, path = fastdtw(lst1[1], lst2[1], dist=euclidean)
            if distance <= distance_threshold:
                cluster[lst1[0]] += [ lst2 ]
                cluster[lst2[0]] += [ lst1 ]
            else:
                donotcluster[lst1[0]] += [ lst2 ]
                donotcluster[lst2[0]] += [ lst1 ]

def hashPair( a, b ): # added this
    return ','.join(max(a,b), min(a,b))
```

Comment: I just need a dictionary that for each id, gives the other id's whose distances were less than some threshold. I have the `donotcluster` dictionary so I don't have to compute a distance if the same symmetric distance was previously found (and shown to not satisfy the threshold).

Comment: My code checks using a `set` instead of a `dict`, which is much more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question about whether there is a more optimized dtw library, but you can use `itertools` to get the combinations you want without duplicates:

```
import itertools

for combination in itertools.combinations(T, 2):
        f(combination[0], combination[1])
```

Here is an example of the combinations:

```
('T_1', 'T_2')
('T_1', 'T_3')
('T_1', 'T_4')
('T_1', 'T_5')
('T_2', 'T_3')
('T_2', 'T_4')
('T_2', 'T_5')
('T_3', 'T_4')
('T_3', 'T_5')
('T_4', 'T_5')
```